# Basic qt app doesn't run but compilied

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, mingw, mingw32

I have created simple qt application: just bare widget. It compilied well, without any problems. Compilied as follows:

`mingw32-make -j5 -f Makefile.Release
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory C:/Users/juriy/test'
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -Wextra -DUNICODE -DQT_DLL -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I'../../../Qt/4.8.6/include/QtCore' -I'../../../Qt/4.8.6/include/QtGui' -I'../../../Qt/4.8.6/include' -I'../../../Qt/4.8.6/include/ActiveQt' -I'release' -I'.' -I'../../../Qt/4.8.6/mkspecs/win32-g++' -o release/main.o main.cpp`

When I starts the application in QtCreator it goes under debug like this:

```
Debugging starts
Debugging has failed
Debugging has finished
```

without debugging mode like this:

```
Starting C:\Users\juriy\test\release\test.exe...
The program has unexpectedly finished.
C:\Users\juriy\test\release\test.exe crashed
```

Under GDB:

```
GNU gdb 6.8
Copyright (C) 2008 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i686-pc-mingw32"...
BFD: BFD (GNU Binutils) 2.18.50.20080226 internal error, aborting at coffcode.h line 842 in handle_COMDAT

BFD: Please report this bug.
```

It seems like I use wrong tools for such a version of Qt. My tools: whole toolchain from `QtSDK 1.2.1` and `Qt 4.8.6`.

I tryed Cygwin packages `make` and `MinGW binutils`, but it abused by lack of cc1plus option `-fno-keep-inline-dllexport`. 
Please, help to understand dependencies of tools and run the application.

Is it right message that gdb was configured as `i686-pc-mingw32` as it pointed above? There is two environments Cygwin and native Windows in my PC. And theres is no like `i686-pc-ming32` names in `C:\QtSDK\mingw\bin`, but simple names as `ar.exe`, `c++filt.exe` etc. Form like `i686-*-mingw32-*` has programs in Cygwin env.

EDIT: (Записи в журнале сообщений Windows)

```
Имя сбойного приложения: test.exe, версия: 0.0.0.0, отметка времени: 0x55912535
Имя сбойного модуля: QtCored4.dll, версия: 4.8.6.0, отметка времени 0x00000000
Код исключения: 0xc0000005
Смещение ошибки: 0x00106acf
Идентификатор сбойного процесса: 0x1340
Время запуска сбойного приложения: 0x01d0b26aab6adef8
Путь сбойного приложения: C:\Users\juriy\test\debug\test.exe
Путь сбойного модуля: C:\Qt\4.8.6\bin\QtCored4.dll
Код отчета: ec353438-1e5d-11e5-b20d-f46d04d35ed7
```

EDIT: Some source to clarify situation.

```
//widget.h
namespace Ui {
class Widget;
}

class Widget : public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Widget(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Widget();

private:
    Ui::Widget *ui;
};
//widget.cpp
Widget::Widget(QWidget *parent) :
    QWidget(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Widget)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Widget::~Widget()
{
    delete ui;
}

// main.cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    Widget w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried building and running one of the sample applications just to be sure that your Qt Creator is configured correctly?

Comment: @nnb, thanks in participation, I didn't tryed so, cause of very basic application run fails. Basic app is good working sample by definition

Comment: Maybe your cygwin config clashed with Qt Creator.. have you tried to use Qt Creator settings to set the toolchain parts and build it from Qt Creator(Options Build & Run, set compiler etc)? I see that you run make manualy from command line.. also you can check the problem in Windows Event Viewer what went wrong (maybe just some lib missing because of wrongly set toolchain paths)

Comment: @otopolsky , I have uninstalled binutils from cygwin and have build with Qt Creator the application -- nevermind. I found messages in windows log, see edit

Comment: exception 0xc00..5 means access violation .. I am just guessing - it can be caused by wrong code, but also broken (dll) file. Maybe you could post some code to check if its really correct.

Comment: @otopolsky, see last edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is important to use the same version of compiler that library was built. [Here](https://wiki.qt.io/MinGW) information about which version was used for building `qt` libraries. Some useful sites that follow me to this decision: [qt centre forum](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/36803-0xc0000005-error-when-using-qVector) and [another one](https://forum.qt.io/topic/44386/unable-to-debug-application-in-qt-creator-3-1-2-qt-5-3-1-on-macos-x/8).